# storing struct info in a vector (text rpg game)

Tags: c++, class, vector, struct

I'm currently writing a text-based RPG for the Game Programming Institute course. I currently have a store in which the character can purchase armor, but now I need to add items to that. I have created a items class, but am having difficulty understanding how I can relate the store class, items class and player class together using a vector array.

I *think* what I should be doing is create a Item vector in the player class that holds information about the struct Items.  Then when the player enters the store, the purchased items are entered into that vector.

I have included, what I feel are, relevant bits of my code. If anyone could give me some pointers or tips just to clear up my brain fog on understanding how to share information across these 3 classes that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

***Item.h***

```
    struct Item{

    int itemType;
    int goldValue;      
};
```

In ***player.h*** class I have added the private data:

```
std::vector<Item> mItem;
```

In ***player.cpp*** I'm attemping to display the items with the function

```
void Player::purchaseItem(Item& mItems, int itemType, int itemValue)
```

Here is ***store.h***

```
    class Store{

public:


    void enterStore(Player& player);



private:

    Armor mStoreArmor;
    int mCost;

};
```

Comment: If you wanted information about sharing information across classes, that's fine. But don't expect anyone to do the job for you.

Comment: What you have so far looks reasonable to me (questions about design are always matters of opinion anyway). What exactly is the question? It helps to be specific, even if you have lots of questions, focus on one to start with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic


"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @john I'm wondering how to I declare item information in the player::purchaseItem function. From my understanding, mItem is a vector that would contain an array of items (each one havingf a itemType, and goldValue) but how do I assign that data in the function. I've tried to pass the vector by reference then state mItem.itemType = 1; but it's not working. Does my question make more sense? Thank you.

Comment: @DavidLeacock Two mistakes there. Firstly mitem is a member of your class, purchaseItem is also a member of your class. Therefore you don't need to pass mitem to playerItem, it automatically has access to the mitem you have already declared in your class. Secondly mitem is (presumably) empty when you start, if you want to add an item to a vector you must use the push_back function. `item an_item; an_item.type = 1; an_item.gold_value = 100; mitem.push_back(an_item);`.

Answer (score 0):

A vector is designed to be a faster dynamically-allocated array.

I would think you'd want to use a hash or just a static array, with either keys or just indices, storing the quantity of each type of item.

you would obviously store possessions in a player class, and have the store class have a list of certain items (possibly with keys for what is in stock - this is why a hash would be a good idea).

When the player sees the store items and chooses one, the quantity in the player class's hash would be incremented.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I definitely don't want anyone to write my code for me, I apologize is if it came across that way. Let me show you what I've tried (which isn't working, obviously) and hopefully you can point out what's wrong with it.  
I'm trying to have an array of items (each one containing the itemType, goldValue data via being a structure). I called that mItem. I tried to add a function in the player class where I pass by reference this Item vector (containing the data) and assign everything that way via  
  
`mItem.itemType = 1;`
`mItem.itenValue = 10;`

Comment: I was taught that there was never a good reason to use a struct. generally, structs are supposed to be only vars (no methods/functions) even though now they are allowed to in c++. Maybe it's just my old professor's opinion, but consider a class instead for objects. Class vars are private by default, where structs' vars are public. Information hiding, or encapsulation, is an important part of OOP that keeps things from getting screwed up later by other parts of the code.

I'll pull up visual studio and give your code a whack tonight since I have the night off.